# Android Studio popup text

Tags: android

I new to Android Studio, still a lot to learn. I'm developing a engineering related app with several different activities, most do calculations and some have results that could be 15 or so lines.
I would like to have the results on a separate page, trying to keep screen clutter down. Does AS have anything like a popup text that I could output to, or would it be better to add another activity that is just a textlist or a table and output to that.
Thanks Steve.

Comment: Please be clear what do you mean by pop up text? Do you mean something like the pop up which has two buttons OK and Close?

Comment: Yes, something like that. But I'd like the option print it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AlertDialogs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog). They have a scrollbar so they can display long texts too.
But for 15 lines you might want a new activity.

A simple Example:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Message")
            .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .create();
alertdialog.show();
```

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at Dialogs, thought there may be something similar but could handle longer message. I've been thinking another activity is probably the way to go, if I design it properly I'll use same activity for all long output results. That way I could probably figure out how to print it as well.